# Is there a way to estimate the remaining time in .net remoting?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, .net-remoting

I got two applications communicating via IPCChannel. 
I call a method(specifically a property.get) that returns a list of 80+ objects, each containing another 500-1000 objects.
This call takes about 40-60 seconds to complete. Is there a way to determine the estimated remaining time in order to give the user some feedback - apart from splitting up the list and fetching the objects one by one (which would make it possible to compute the remaining time myself)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting the communication up into smaller pieces is actually a pretty good way to solve this problem.

You need to have an initial handshaking communication to establish how many pieces are to be used, but then you can give an accurate estimate of the time to go. Make sure that you don't break it up into pieces that are so small that the communication overhead degrades performance.

Comment: So there is no build in method to do this?

Comment: @yas I would doubt it. I think this is the sort of thing that frameworks leave to the callers to determine exactly how best to do it.